# How to display .cfg file in the graph form using GCC compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

steps executed.

1. Created C/C++ program and kept in CYGWIN64.
2. gcc -fdump-tree-cfg Hello.c executed. (in CygWin64 command)
3. Hello.cfg file generated.
4. After this I am not able to show the Hello.cfg file in the form graphical form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-fdump-tree-cfg-graph` to get a graphviz .dot file, on which you can then use the dot tool from graphviz to convert a to a graphical format.

If you happen to have an X server running, you can also use `dot -Tx11 Hello.c.013t.cfg.dot` (or whatever the name of the file ands up being) to display the graph directly without converting it to another file format first.